# Notepad++ with avr-gcc error

Tags: gcc, notepad++, avr

I want to create a run command in notepad++, that cleans/deletes the compiled files whenever I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>. So far I created this line of code :

```
cmd /k c:\WinAVR-20100110\utils\bin\make.exe make clean $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)
```

It does not work and gives this warning :

> No Rule To make target clean

Which technically means the parameter is wrong, however I did not find a way to correct it.

Any Suggestions

Comment: I don't know the syntax Notepad++ uses. But the message comes from the make program. It seems the make understand it has to create the project named "clean".

Comment: How do you know that `make` is reading the correct `makefile`? What is the "current directory" when the command is executed?

Comment: I think that after make.exe you haven't to use the parameter `make`. I think the command to be executed should be: `[...]\make.exe clean $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)` where `FULL_CURRENT_PATH` should be the path of the makefile that contains the instructions to manage the project.

Comment: ohh i get it ,the reason was i gave the full path to it (meaning from C:\ to the c file ,which will not work because there need to be a Makefile in the directory(which i placed already).So my question now will be "What is an alternative of $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH), that will make notepad++ look into the Target Directory rather than the Target File"?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to pass `make` as an argument to `make` because then it will look for a target named `make` which is not defined.

Also, you would need to make sure `make` is running in the right directory.  One way to do that is use the `-C` option.  For example:

```
make -C path/to/my/dir clean
```

Some unsolicited tips:  WinAVR is really old, see how you are using the version from 2010-01-10?  I'd recommend using [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/) for your Bash shell environment and then installing the latest [AVR 8-bit toolchain from Atmel](http://www.atmel.com/tools/atmelavrtoolchainforwindows.aspx).